# How to send mail on behalf of Google apps address with Gmail?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, google-apps-email, smtp

#### Context

I got a Google apps for `my-google-apps.com` and what to be able to send mail on behalf of this domain through my Gmail address that I use as primary address.

#### Settings

- Send mail as: `Coding Goûter <codinggouter@my-google-apps.com>` ;
- Mail is sent through: `smtp-relay.gmail.com` ;
- Secured connection on port `587` using `TLS`.

#### Error

```
Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:

     test@me.fr

Technical details of permanent failure:
read error: generic::failed_precondition: read error (0): error

----- Original message -----

X-Gm-Message-State: ALyK8tKwKBrOQHPiS4ZRUe54UUxBmujgWZw20aXORPT2T3wvaMYh8keekpQmHw1bQj/clA+dprC+WZ0TJUYwEg==
X-Received: by 10.25.23.8 with SMTP id n8mr2876085lfi.205.1468225620148; Mon,
 11 Jul 2016 01:27:00 -0700 (PDT)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Received: by 10.25.146.142 with HTTP; Mon, 11 Jul 2016 01:26:20 -0700 (PDT)
From: =?UTF-8?Q?Coding_Go=C3=BBter?= <codinggouter@my-google-apps.com>
Date: Mon, 11 Jul 2016 10:26:20 +0200
X-Gmail-Original-Message-ID: <CAHGFyZTgbiKGQnm4OB8Sin5VobfTCawshodU+srw71LgKeu2XQ@mail.gmail.com>
Message-ID: <CAHGFyZTgbiKGQnm4OB8Sin5VobfTCawshodU+srw71LgKeu2XQ@mail.gmail.com>
Subject: test
To: test@me.fr
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=001a114080488a0724053757ea31
```

#### Question

How do I setup this? Is the SMTP configure incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

#### Check the following

1. [use **Gmail SMTP server**](https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en) ;

   > **Gmail SMTP server** - requires authentication with your Gmail/Google
   >   Apps account and password. Messages can be sent to anyone inside or
   >   outside of your domain.
2. (not sure) enable [Allow less secure apps: `ON`](https://myaccount.google.com/u/1/security?utm_source=OGB&pli=1) setting.

#### Config

- Send mail as: `Coding Goûter <codinggouter@my-google-apps.com>` ;
- Mail is sent through: **`smtp.gmail.com`** ;
- Secured connection on port `587` using `TLS`.